# Multiple data packets with CIPSEND, associate each with pathway

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

When using a CIPSEND from an Arduino Uno to a ESP8266 connected to the Uno is there a way to associate the data packet sent with a pathway so it can be retrieved at said pathway from the browser?

For example ESP8266WebServer.h has a command like this:

```
server.on(“/specificArgs”, handleSpecificArg);   //Associate the handler function to the path
```

where the first argument is the path/filename - what's the equivalent of this using using CIPSEND?

Comment: The Arduino sends the CIPSEND to the ESP8266, not the other way around. It's hard to understand quite what you're asking.

Comment: I have rephrased the question. Refer to the ESP8266WebServer.h example here https://techtutorialsx.com/2016/10/22/esp8266-webserver-getting-query-parameters/ and you will see what I mean about associating the data packet with a path/filename.

Comment: So you are using the Arduino and ESP8266 as a web server?  The browser sends a request with a path in it, and your CIPSEND is what you send in response to that. The "association" is the fact that you are responding to a request.

Comment: https://github.com/khoih-prog/ESP8266_AT_WebServer

Comment: @Juraj useful as a last resort but I'd prefer to get it working with the AT commands rather than jump from that to a library.

Answer (score 0):

Your "CIPSEND" is already associated with a path.

The sequence is generally:

1. You configure the ESP8266 as a server, including turning on multiple connections
2. You browse to the IP
3. The browser sends a HTTP request including a path. This has a "channel" number associated with it.
4. You generate a HTTP response and send it to the channel given in 3 using `AT+CIPSEND`.

The fact that you're sending the response to the browser through the channel that the request came in through "associates" the response with the request.

To do different things depending on the path it's up to you to recognise that path in the request and generate a different response accordingly.

Comment: "To do different things depending on the path it's up to you to recognise that path in the request and generate a different response accordingly." - yes how? If i want the first datapacket sent to the esp8266 to be associated with '192.168.4.1/' and the second to be associated with 192.168.4.1/data', how is that done?

Comment: When you receive the request to get / you send the response for /.  When you receive the request for /data you send the response for /data.

Comment: Ok I think I'm beginning to understand what you mean - If I understand correctly I should be doing a `esp8266.find("/");` and `esp8266.find("/data");` in my arduino code and then an `if ()` to determine what path has been requested by the esp8266. I need to test this as there is an added complexity I didn't mention in my question. Data packet 1 is a webpage with ajax, data packet 2 is an json string. The json is constantly being updated by the arduino, the ajax webpage is directly requesting the ajax. As far as I understand this doesn't change anything but need to test...